# Is it possible to have one static controller instead of creating new ones at every request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, static, singleton

By every Request it generates a new Instance of my Controller. I have a private Model in my Controller and I want to work and modify this **ONE** Instance.

```
public class CreateTableController : Controller
{
    private CreateTableModels model = new CreateTableModels();
}
```

Do I need to store it somewhere on the server or client?

Is this somehow possible, or am i even doing it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I believe you can't make static controllers... But you can make your model static

Comment: Controller are created on each request, because its only purpose is to serve one single request and be disposed. Static models are pointless. What you want is absolutly normal and commonly know as "service". Web app can have several singleton services which can be injected to controllers with somekind Dependency Injection (DI)

Comment: @vasily.sib you are a fan of my question, right? ;) thanks for your help, i will take a look into services

Comment: The Biggest fan, yeah:) Better look for Dependency Injection first, then choice one of dozens DI-Containers, that works nicely with ASP.Net MVC, and only then look how services imlemented for this DI-Container